github repository not resolve
i have change my system. in my project i use github repository. In my old studio this repositories work very well but in current system most of them do not resolve.
i am getting this error:

Here is my build gradle:
plugins {
    id 'com.android.application'
}

android {
    compileSdk 32

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.sabirkhansahebsons"
        minSdk 21
        targetSdk 32
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"

        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
}

dependencies {

    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.7.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.12.0'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.1.4'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.13.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.2.1'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.6.1'
    implementation 'com.github.armcha:ElasticView:0.2.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-storage:21.0.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:23.0.0'
    implementation 'androidx.legacy:legacy-support-v4:1.0.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:21.0.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-dynamic-links:22.0.0'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.13.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.5'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.5.1'
    implementation 'com.hbb20:ccp:2.3.1'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.12.0'
    implementation 'com.firebase:firebase-client-android:2.4.0'
    implementation 'com.chaos.view:pinview:1.4.3'
    implementation 'com.ismaeldivita.chipnavigation:chip-navigation-bar:1.3.2'
    implementation 'org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:1.9.20'
    implementation 'com.facebook.shimmer:shimmer:0.5.0'
    implementation 'de.hdodenhof:circleimageview:3.1.0'
    implementation 'com.github.pratikbutani:MultiSelectSpinner:f47c0dadea'
    implementation 'androidx.multidex:multidex:2.0.1'
    implementation 'io.apptik.widget:multiselectspinner:1.0.12'
    implementation 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.3.1'
    implementation 'com.github.armcha:ElasticView:0.2.0'
    implementation 'net.danlew:android.joda:2.9.5.1'
    implementation 'devs.mulham.horizontalcalendar:horizontalcalendar:1.3.4'
    implementation 'com.android.volley:volley:1.2.1'
    implementation 'com.karumi:dexter:6.2.3'
    implementation 'androidx.browser:browser:1.8.0'
    implementation 'com.ernestoyaquello.stepperform:vertical-stepper-form:2.7.0'
    implementation 'me.drozdzynski.library.steppers:steppers:1.0.0'
    implementation 'org.apache.commons:commons-collections4:4.4'
    implementation 'commons-net:commons-net:3.6'
    implementation 'org.jsoup:jsoup:1.10.2'
    implementation 'com.github.florent37:tutoshowcase:1.0.1'
    implementation('com.razorpay:checkout:1.6.20')


    //Butterknife
    implementation 'com.jakewharton:butterknife:8.8.1'
    implementation 'com.github.yalantis:ucrop:2.2.2'
    implementation 'com.google.android.play:core:1.10.3'
}

here is my setting gradle:
pluginManagement {
    repositories {
        gradlePluginPortal()
        google()
        mavenCentral()
    }
}
dependencyResolutionManagement {
    repositoriesMode.set(RepositoriesMode.FAIL_ON_PROJECT_REPOS)
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
        jcenter()
        maven { url 'https://jitpack.io' }
    }
}

rootProject.name = "SabirKhansahebSons"
include ':app'

here is my build gradle:
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.
plugins {
    id 'com.android.application' version '7.2.0' apply false
    id 'com.android.library' version '7.2.0' apply false
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}

I know about add  maven { url 'https://jitpack.io' } in setting gradle. but this will not resolve any dependency also i am on stable internet connection too. still problem was same. i don't know what i am doing wrong.

Those dependencies no longer exist. Either you need to update to newer versions that do exist or remove those dependencies.
For example, let's look at com.github.armcha:ElasticView:0.2.0. This was released nearly six years ago on JCenter. You were supposed to stop relying on JCenter a few years ago, and JCenter finally shut down a month or so ago. And, if you look at the project site for that library, it was abandoned about six years ago.
The sensible thing to do would be to stop using this library and to find some other solution for whatever problem you were trying to solve with it. Alternatively, you could fork that GitHub repo, build the library yourself, and put it somewhere for your project to use (e.g., in Maven Local). However, you then are responsible for maintaining all that code as well.
For each of the dependencies that Gradle cannot resolve, you will need to do that same sort of analysis.

FWIW, I wrote more about this situation in my blog.

There are no errors but warnings. As I see on the right side of your screenshot, Build is successful. Seems like a new AndroidStudio using a newer gradle version and some old features that some of your libs are using are deprecated in this version. I suggest you update your libs version to get rid of this warnings.

but this dependency not resolve thats means i don't use all of them which not resolve
